# A word to describe the type of literature read on toilet?

Tags: terminology, slang

Is there an English word (recognised or slang) that describes the type of literature that is intended to be read in the toilet/bathroom/restroom?

I've seen books in the past that seemed aimed directly at this kind of market, but a recent discussion led to me looking for a term to describe this 'genre' (if it can be called that).

I'm thinking of terms along the lines of 'chick-lit', 'pulp fiction', 'coffee table book' etc.

If there is no established word/term, suggestions?

Comment: I can't think of a standard phrase, but "potty prose" is catchy - if you'd like to try and start a trend. Sometimes my husband looks through the bookshelves for something "motivational."

Comment: Is 'shit lit' too obvious?

Comment: *Toilet tomes*?

Comment: Or maybe *lav-lit*?

Comment: Bog standard...?

Comment: As a prototype of Twitter it could perhaps (not unreasonably) be referred to as "shitter."

Comment: As I recall, "The Big Chill" defined it as "People Magazine".

Comment: Lavatory literature is an improvement on toilet literature

Comment: Johnalism. And I never understood *Reader's Digest* - shouldn't it be *Digester's Read*?

Answer (score 3):

It is called ***toilet literature***.

- *[Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=toilet%20literature)* has an entry for this term:

> newspapers, national geographic any magazine is good for toilet literature
>
> *A: Man it's part of the ritual u gotta read some shit u don't care about to take a good shit*
> *B: Word.*

- *[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/genres/toilet-literature)* lists some books under *toilet literature* genre.
- There is an article titled "[Is the iPhone threatening to kill off toilet literature?](http://www.itsnicethat.com:8080/articles/is-the-iphone-killing-toilet-literature)"

> The National Geographic makes for excellent toilet literature. It does a great job of proving to anybody who might be visiting you that you’re the National Geographic reading type, and that you choose to improve your otherwise limited brain while hanging out on the throne.
>
> For years now the National Geographic, alongside the likes of Time magazine and Art Review, has been bringing culture to time-spent-on-the-toilet worldwide. It brings some sophistication to going for a wee. And it’s come under threat in recent years due to the arrival of the iPhone.
>
> <sub>Maisie Skidmore / itsnicethat.com</sub>

- An excerpt from the book "No Amish Need Apply" *By Kurt Ringquist*:

> One staple of American **toilet literature** I have not touched upon, one that is familiar to any American who has browsed the Humor section of a bookstore, is, of course, the one, the only, **Uncle John's Bathroom Reader**, in its many forms and variations.

- *Toilet literature* doodle:

[image]

Comment: "Toilet reading" is the term I've always heard.

Answer (score 2):

IMO- If we can have a *coffee-table* book, why not a  *[potty-seat book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_John's_Bathroom_Reader)*.

Comment: Hmm … “The books are credited to the Bathroom Readers' Institute […] and are published by Portable Press” … shouldn’t that be _Portaloo Press_?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "**loo books**". See the discussion in the English Spectator [here](http://www.spectator.co.uk/books/books-secondary-feature/9373692/the-10-best-loo-books-of-2014-why-we-sing-so-much-better-in-the-shower-and-what-became-of-queen-victorias-childrens-milk-teeth/).

(If the books are kept in the lavatory because they are obscene, it would be difficult to improve on Rousseau's "**books to be read with one hand**").

Comment: To Americanize, also include "Bathroom Book" -- there's a series published ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_American_Bathroom_Book ) which specifically capitalizes on this phrase.